# Change my_list[1] to my_list[9] by adding 8 when reaching an if statement

Tags: python

I need to be able to change "X" of the my_list[X] value once reaching an if statement by adding a number to the value.  Here's a basic example of my code:

```
with open("*/file.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
my_list = data.splitlines()

print(my_list[1])
```

Result:

```
Line 1 of my_list
```

What I need:

```
if sky = blue
    my_list[+8]
print(my_list[9]) #the result of my_list[1] +8
```

Resulting in

```
Line 9 of my_list
```

I have a total of 8 my_list[X] values, and I need to be able to add 8 to the [X] number to automatically select the next set of lines once the if statement is reached (kinda repeated myself there).

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: It could be helpful if you can post an example of ```file.txt```

Comment: Why can't you do `if sky == blue: print(my_list[9])`? Your question is really not clear

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `readlines()` instead of using `read()` followed by `splitlines()`?

Comment: The above code is an example.  I have a total of 8 my_list[X] lines, each containing different data.  Python is calling these lines from a .txt file, and once a certain condition is reached, I need the X value of my_list to increase by 8 (to call the next 8 lines), until the condition is met again, then increase by another 8, on to infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would do the trick!

```
i=1
with open("*/file.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
my_list = data.splitlines()

while True:
    print(my_list[i])
    # do stuff 

    if "sky" == "blue":
         i+=8
     
    # MUST specify exit condition
```

**But do not forget to specify the exit condition and account for "IndexError: list index out of range"!**

Answer (score 0):

This code iterates over all the lines of `my_data`
and if the if statement is true for a certain line, the line in `index+8` will be changed:

```
with open("*/file.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
my_list = data.splitlines()
for index,line in enumerate(my_list):
    if "sky"=="blue": #or any other if statement that depends on "line"
        my_list[index+8] = "change row i+8 here"
```